# Comparing `list`s in python

Tags: python, list, unique, set

I have multiple lists. I need to find a way to generate list of unique items in each list as compared with all the lists.  Is there any simple or straight forward way to do this.  I know that these lists can basically be used as `set`s.

Comment: Use `set()`, what else do you need?

Comment: So for every list, you want to find the elements of it that are not in any of the other lists?

Comment: There's a little more logic than just 'set()' to find out what's unique to each list.

Comment: I think he/she means 'for each list, generate items that occur in that list, but no others.'

Comment: @phooji is correct, I am sorry that I was not clear earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import collections

def uniques(*args):
    """For an arbitrary number of sequences,
           return the items in each sequence which
            do not occur in any of the other sequences
    """

    # ensure that each value only occurs once in each sequence
    args = [set(a) for a in args]

    seen = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for a in args:
        for i in a:
            seen[i] += 1
    # seen[i] = number of sequences in which value i occurs

    # for each sequence, return items
    #  which only occur in one sequence (ie this one)
    return [[i for i in a if seen[i]==1] for a in args]
```

so

```
uniques([1,1,2,3,5], [2,3,4,5], [3,3,3,9])  ->  [[1], [4], [9]]
```

Comment: Novel. But using the set API is more Pythonic, don't you think?

Comment: @santa: except that this prevents the need to compose all possible combinations of (n-1) sets.

Answer (score 4):

Use the set class and the set operations defined therein:

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,5]
>>> l2 = [3,4,4,6,7]
>>> set(l1) ^ set(l2)    # symmetric difference
set([1, 2, 5, 6, 7])
```

*edit*: Ah, misread your question. If you meant, "unique elements in `l1` that is not in any of `l2, l3, ..., ln`, then:

```
l1set = set(l1)
for L in list_of_lists:   # list_of_lists = [l2, l3, ..., ln]
    l1set = l1set - set(L)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l1 = [4, 6, 3, 7]
l2 = [5, 5, 3, 1]
l3 = [2, 5, 4, 3]
l4 = [9, 8, 7, 6]

# first find the union of the "other" lists
l_union = reduce(set.union, (map(set, (l1, l2, l3))))

# then subtract the union from the remaining list
uniques = set(l4) - l_union

print uniques
```

and the result:

```
>>> set([8, 9])
```

Comment: For n input lists, you must repeat this process n times (items of l1 not in l2,l3,l4, items of l2 not in l1,l3,l4, items of l3 not in l1,l2,l4, items of l4 not in l1,l2,l3).

Answer (score 0):

```
for l in lists:
  s = set(l)
  for o in lists:
    if o != l:
      s -= set(o)

  # At this point, s holds the items unique to l
```

For efficiency, you could convert all the lists to sets once.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

# Test set
lists = []
lists.append([1,2,3,4,5,5])
lists.append([3,4,4,6,7])
lists.append([7,])
lists.append([8,9])
lists.append([10,10])

# Join all the lists removing the duplicates in each list
join_lists = []
for list_ in lists:
    join_lists.extend(set(list_))

# First, sort
join_lists.sort()

# Then, list only the groups with one element
print [ key for key, grp in itertools.groupby(join_lists) if len(list(grp)) < 2 ]

#>>> [1, 2, 6, 8, 9]

###
```

Comment: If one group contains multiple instances of a value (ie 4) it will be disqualified even if no other groups contain it.